# Translate LINQ to SQL query to NHibernate (child collection filter)

Tags: c#, nhibernate

What is the correct translation of this LINQ to SQL query in NHibernate using the Criteria API?

```
var result = from e in Employees
    where e.WorkTimeEntries.Any(t => t.DateTime >= new DateTime(2012, 3, 1))
    select e;
```

I have tried:

```
var employees       = Session.QueryOver<Employee>();
var timeWorkedAlias = new HashedSet<WorkTimeEntry>();
var timeWorked      = employees.Left.JoinQueryOver(e => e.WorkTimes,
                                                        () => timeWorkedAlias);
timeWorkedAlias.Where (wa => wa.DateTime >= new DateTime(2012,3,1));
// How do to include the timeWorkedAlias 'filter' in the  query?

var result = employees.List();
```

I am missing a couple of steps to include the date filter to be included in the query.

Comment: Working with criteria is awful, why do not using linq2nhibernate?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, I wish I could, however Linq2NHibernate has its own set of limitations and I am forced to use the criteria api :(

Comment: @Saeed Amiri The NHibrnate LINQ provider is a joke. I will never again use NHibernate if I get to make the decision for precisely this reason.

Comment: @Stilgar, currently I'm using nhibernate2linq, it's better than awful criteria and you can do too many things with it. and everything which is impossible with nhibernate2linq can be done by native query or so. In all I agree with you that nhibernate is not good when we have better options.

Comment: Every time I have to write something more complex than a `get` query in NHibernate my pants start to shiver ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I manage to find the answer (with help from Andre)

This seems to work:

```
var result = Session.QueryOver<Employee>()
 .JoinQueryOver<WorkTimeEntry>(e => e.WorkTimes)
 .Where(t => t.DateTime > new DateTime(2012,3,1))
 .List();
```

The trick is to specify `JoinQueryOver<WorkTimeEntry>`

According to [QueryOver in NH 3.0](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx)

> Note, the overload for JoinQueryOver takes an IEnumerable, and the
>   C# compiler infers the type from that. If your collection type is not
>   IEnumerable, then **you need to qualify the type of the sub-criteria**:

Comment: Ah OK, I didn't know WorkTimes wasn't IEnumerable. Also I had a minor typo in my example. Anyway, great if I could help.

Answer (score 3):

I can't test it right now, but this *should* work:

```
var result = Session.QueryOver<Employee>()
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.WorkTimes)
    .Where(wt=> wt.DateTime >= new DateTime(2012, 3, 1))
    .List();
```

It *should* filter the parent entity (Employee) based on the property of the child collection (because it's an inner join). But again, I haven't tested it.

Comment: thanks for the answer but unfortunately it fails to compile.  Error message: `Delegate 'System.Func<bool>' does not take 1 arguments Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'NHibernate.Criterion.ICriterion' because it is not a delegate type`.

Comment: I managed to find the answer with your help.  It seems I had to qualify the `JoinQueryOvery` because WorkTime does not implement IEnumerable (no way you would have known with the limited example).